# Highlighting certain nodes/edges in NetworkX - Issues with using zip()

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I able to populate network graph using networkx. My problem is when I want to highlight the path (shortest path for example) the graph cannot generate and it will return error below.

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gr,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r',width=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py", line 578, in draw_networkx_edges
    if not edgelist or len(edgelist) == 0:  # no edges!
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()
```

I look for solution and this is because the script is running over python3 and due to that I get this error. One of the solution is to change and add list as below.

original:

```
Gr = nx.DiGraph() 
edges = graph
Gr.add_edges_from(edges)
pos = nx.spring_layout(Gr)

path = nx.shortest_path(Gr,source=1,target=7)
path_edges = zip(path,path[1:])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Gr,pos,nodelist=path,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gr,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r',width=10)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Modified:

```
path = nx.shortest_path(Gr,source=1,target=7)
path_edges = list(zip(path,path[1:]))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Gr,pos,nodelist=path,node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gr,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r',width=10)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Able to run the script no error and able to generate graph but the highlighted path (red) is not aligned to the topology node and link. The red path should be on-top and align of node/path 1-2-3-4-5-6-7. Please refer to images below

[image: image1]
[image: image3]
[image: image3]

Please advise how to resolve this problem.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. I would raise an issue on their github page.

Comment: I'm still work on it...will update you guyz...thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to generate the graph you appear to be after with the following code - let me know if you encounter any issues. You were correct that you need to convert the `zip` object to a `list`, but I think there may be other mistakes in your drawing code. If you need the output from `nx.spring_layout` to be the same every time, you can use the `seed` keyword argument, for example `pos = nx.spring_layout(Gr, seed=123)`.

**Code:**

```
import networkx as nx

# Set up graph
Gr = nx.DiGraph() 
edges = [(i+1, i+2) for i in range(10)] + [(i+2, i+1) for i in range(10)]
Gr.add_edges_from(edges)

# Get position using spring layout
pos = nx.spring_layout(Gr)

# Get shortest path
path = nx.shortest_path(Gr,source=1,target=7)
path_edges = list(zip(path,path[1:]))

# Draw nodes and edges not included in path
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Gr, pos, nodelist=set(Gr.nodes)-set(path))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gr, pos, edgelist=set(Gr.edges)-set(path_edges), connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.3')

# Draw nodes and edges included in path
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Gr, pos, nodelist=path, node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gr,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r', connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.3')

# Draw labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(Gr,pos)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This should work...let me test it...anyway...how to make the graph fix (the node/link fix at their position)...thanks

Comment: @chenoi that's what the pos variable is for.

Comment: Yup....it work..now..look like your sample..the arrow is correct...but how to make the node/link topology fix into its coordinate ....because every time i run the script the output topology node/link will change coordinate or position...what i mean is...for example the topology output could be vertical...than execute again the script and it will output the topology as horizontal... it will not output as the node/link at the same position... i tried using fixed...but didnt work...thanks...

Comment: @chenoi see the update to my answer - use the `seed` keyword argument to `spring_layout`.