# How to remove the last edge of a subgraph using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I was hoping that you can helped me with this. I created a graph using an adjacency matrix with the next code.

```
graph = nx.from_numpy_array(adjacency_matrix, create using = nx.DiGraph)
mypos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos = mypos)
```

and then I get the shortest path...

```
path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 3, 2)
print(path)
```

Which give me the next path

```
[3,1,2]
```

I was triying to draw the path creating a subgraph using the nodes given by the shortest path.

```
subgraph = graph.subgraph(path)
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos = mypos, arrows = True)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(H, pos = mypos, node_color = 'r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(H, pos = mypos, edge_color = 'r')
```

And I get the next result

[image: Figura]

The problem is, even though it was draw, they added a new extra edge between node 2 and 3 that I don't want, is there a way to change this so I don't have that extra edge? I know that networkx can remove an edge using nx.remove_edge() but I don't want to be removing edges manually every time I run the program and choosing another path.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem you don't need a subgraph. You can highlight the path and the node with the following code, which is a simplification of the accepted answer from [Highlighting certain nodes/edges in NetworkX - Issues with using zip()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164893/highlighting-certain-nodes-edges-in-networkx-issues-with-using-zip).

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

# Set up graph
graph = nx.DiGraph(nx.karate_club_graph())

# Get position using spring layout
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)

# Get shortest path
path = nx.shortest_path(graph, 0, 9)
# if you want to draw fewer edges, you can modify the following line by setting limits
path_edges = list(zip(path,path[1:]))

# Draw nodes and edges not included in path
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos, node_color='k', nodelist=set(graph.nodes)-set(path))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos, edgelist=set(graph.edges)-set(path_edges))

# Draw nodes and edges included in path
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos, nodelist=path, node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph,pos,edgelist=path_edges,edge_color='r')

pl.axis("off")
pl.show()
```

Comment: Yes it works! thank you so much! So basically it's drawing a graph over a graph right? Is there a way to transfer the weights of my original graph to the new one? So I can get the length of the shortest path?

Comment: In the same way, you can add the edge weights for that path to the figure. Take a look here for the general approach of adding edge weights: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094949/labeling-edges-in-networkx. If you need help after checking that source, then I modify my answer. As another remark, now you should have enough reputation to add the image directly. If you answer your question, it would help others with the same question.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yes in the figure appears the weights but what I mean is, I want to print the length of the shortest path, the thing is when the shortest path was draw in the figure, every edge  of the shortest path has the weight of 1, but I want the weight of the original graph, can I transfer the numerical value of the weight of my original graph to the new?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your problem is. Where do you lose your weights? Only for the visualisation or do you create a subgraph? If it's longer its probably the best idea to post a new question with a minimal working example (or if its only a small think modify this question)